# Dynamic image display in Android

Tags: android, image

I need to have a folder where images are downloaded. Then iterate through the contents of that folder to show images one by one for pre-set time period. My screen is divided into three parts:

- in the first row, there are 2 columns: list view and image view
- the second row has an image view.

My main focus is on displaying the images. My issue is how to create the image view, since the image resources are not in res folder of Android, it is determined at run time. I cannot place images into image view with the `android:src="@drawable/android"` tag.

I ran the debugger but control does not go into the `if (file.isDirectory())` block. I have folder named `ServiceMobile2` in `H:/` phone card.

```
<-xml file->
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ffffff">
    <!-- Row 1 with single column -->
     <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/personal_contacts"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="number"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
    <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Save" />
     </TableRow>
      <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Delete" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView> 
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

     </TableRow>  
         <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
      </TableRow> 
    </TableLayout>


public void getFromSdcard()
{   
    File file=  new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"serviceMobile2");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file printer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        listFile = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
        {
            mFileStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("...................................."+mFileStrings[i]);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mFileStrings[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            ImageView iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? you should load images from memory where they're saved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907920/loop-through-an-image-folder-and-show-in-imageview-android. The above question is probably related to the one in the link. Please provide logcat details if your getting an exception

Comment: So is your question why doesn't `file.isDirectory()` return `true` in your program?  Is `serviceMobile2` a directory on the SDCARD?

Comment: if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){ do something} check if sd card is mounted

Comment: there is only one memory showing on my phone H:/phone memory

Comment: File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"serviceMobile2"); print file.getAbsolutePath(); it should print the path if serviceMobile2 exists

Comment: so, is there no way to retrive data if sdcard is not mounted. But I have a directory named ServiceMobile2 somewhere in memory, I see it when connect through usb